# What is hows.info?

Tags: discussion

I've stumbled across a website: `http://hows.info`.

It appears to be a mirror or clone of StackOverflow.

What is it?

**Update:** I've followed the instructions and I see that it has already been reported.  Thank you.

Comment: Rising Star, please look at the post linked by Ben and report it there if it fits. Thanks for the report!

Comment: That site should be reported on the link provided by Ben!

Comment: What actually happens to sites identified as clones then?

Comment: Interesting that I found this site using Google Webmaster Tools.  It copied a link to my personal web site from StackOverflow.